# How do i compile(run) just a part of the code in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a little bit long code with few exercises (learning to code) and i need to run just part of the code to compile so i don't have to go through all the stuff i wrote before in the console. Is there any keyboard shortcut for it ?

Comment: Have you learnt about unit tests yet?

Comment: Just comment out the exercises you don't want to test

Comment: Essentially if the code is all in a single assembly it will always be compiled by the C# compiler to create the assembly. There is no way to compile just part of an assembly. But why would you need to? Compiling is fast. What is the problem with compiling it all at once? Edit: I see you wrote (run) in brackets - running is very different to compiling. Perhaps the question isn't clear...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creat new class
Put your target code in a public method of your class in a new project - call it project A

Create another project of type UnitTest 
Reference your project A

In test project, 
Create a class
Create a method
Call your project A method